# PpMemory.cpp missing when generating Vulkan-Samples MSVC project

Tags: c++, cmake, vulkan

I am trying to build the [Vulkan-Samples](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples) from the Khronos git repo for Windows. I cloned and built the dependencies [glslang](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang) and [Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers), and followed all the configuration and build steps as described. As far as I could tell there was no issue, but now when I try to generate project files with `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64 ../.."` from within my build directory as described [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples/blob/master/BUILDING.md), I get the following error:

> CMake Error at external/libs/glslang/CMakeLists.txt:133 (add_library):
>
> Cannot find source file:
>
> D:/Khronos/glslang/glslang/MachineIndependent/preprocessr/PpMemory.cpp
>
> Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
>     .hxx .in .txx
>
> CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: glslang

Indeed, the file is missing, but I wasn't able to find out where it's supposed to come from or what steps I've missed. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried commenting the line and checking that the file is actually needed for the build to succeed? Or perhaps re-downloading the repository and seeing if this was a glitch that was picked up after you downloaded it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That file is no longer part of glslang and has been removed from it's repository last year and is therefore no longe required to built the glslang libraries.

I guess they forgot to update their samples repository to reflect these changes.

So to get the samples to compile either remove `PpMemory.cpp` and `PpSymbols.cpp` from the cmakelists.txt or (better) use the one from the current [glslang repository](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/blob/master/glslang/CMakeLists.txt).

A small note: The Khronos Vulkan samples repository never really took off, so you may instead want to take a look at other examples packs like the [official ones from LunarG](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples) or those from my own repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although the project is now generated, I still get a few build errors regarding hlsl -- the samples repo doesn't seem to be up to date. Anyways, thanks also for your note, this is valuable to know. I am currently trying to figure out where to start and meant to begin with as close to the VK API as possible. As far as I understand the LunarG stuff is more high-level as it builds upon their SDK, so I thought I'd better move to the Khronos samples. I also checked out your samples already earlier, maybe this is a good starting point.